# Istead of replacing a part of a string with the value associated with the key 22, it just replaces it with the value associated with key 2, 2 times

Tags: python

I am converting information about a delivery from a file given to me, it contains information like this:
name, item_number, item_number, item_number
for example
Joe, 2, 22, 10, 17

The issue is whenever i try to replace the number in the line, with a value associated with the key, which is indetical to the item_number from the file, it returns for example the value associated with 2, x2 times instead of the value associated with 22.

```
import sys
f = open("testFil.txt", "r")
list_of_lists = []

items = {
    1: "Cigaretter",
    2: "Snus",
    3: "Kaffe",
    4: "Te",
    5: "Solbriller",
    6: "Mørk Chokolade",
    7: "Kiks",
    8: "Harebo Mix",
    9: "Salt Chips",
    10: "Pepper Chips",
    11: "Sour Cream Chips",
    12: "Oreo",
    13: "Ritter Sport",
    14: "Chokolade Kiks",
    15: "Mælk",
    16: "Sukker",
    17: "Brød",
    18: "Kuglepen",
    19: "Juice",
    20: "Avis",
    21: "Toilet Papir",
    22: "Tandbørste",
    23: "Kondomer",
    24: "Tandpasta",
    25: "Køkkenrulle"}

with open("testFil.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.replace("\n","")
        for i in items:
            line = line.replace(str(i), items[i])
        list_of_lists.append(line.split(", "))


for i in list_of_lists:
    for j in i:
        if i.count(j) > 1:
            i[i.index(j)] = str(i.count(j)) + "x " + j
            for k in range(i.count(j)):
                i.remove(j)

customer_count = -1



def last_customer():
    print("This is the last order")
    print(list_of_lists[next_customer()])

def luk_programmet():
    sys.exit()

def next_customer():
    global customer_count
    customer_count += 1
    return customer_count

def print_customer():
    a = input("")
    if a == "Next Order":
        if customer_count == len(list_of_lists) - 2:
            print("This is the last order")
            print(list_of_lists[next_customer()])
            luk_programmet()
        else:
            try:
                print(list_of_lists[next_customer()])
            except IndexError:
                print("This is the last order")
                luk_programmet()

    elif a == "/close the program":
        luk_programmet()

    else:
        print("You typed it wrong.")
        print_customer()

#Prints the customer list

print("Write 'Next Order' to recieve the next order")
for i in range(len(list_of_lists)):
    if print_customer() == "Done":
        sys.exit()
    print_customer()
```

The txt file:

```
Joe, 1, 2, 1, 8
Micky, 19, 19, 15, 13
Berta, 4, 3, 3, 3
Frede, 24, 22, 8, 2
per, 1, 9, 18, 24
```

I have tried making the key into a string, in the hopes that would help, but that didn't work out.

Comment: Are there always 4 item numbers per person, or is that a variable number of items?

Comment: The variable number of items, the codes is made so it can accept an infinite amount of items per person, but the problem is instead of replacing the number 22, with the item associated with 22, it just replaces it with the items associated with 2, x2 times.
I hope that didn't sound confusing

Comment: @Mikkel please [edit] that info into your post instead of putting it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The core problem you have is that you're performing *string replacement*, which as you've observed, replaces every instance of "2" with a value.

To illustrate:

```
>>> "222".replace("2", "something")
'somethingsomethingsomething'
```

So, what's a better approach?

Given the following file contents as a source:

```
Joe, 1, 2, 1, 8
Micky, 19, 19, 15, 13
Berta, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3
Frede, 24, 22, 8, 2
per, 1, 9, 18, 24, 12, 22, 1, 23
```

We can use Python's inbuild [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) library to parse the file contents, and do some funky stuff with [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter):

```py
with open("testFil.txt") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=["person"], restkey="items", skipinitialspace=True)

    for row in reader:
        item_names = []
        
        for item in row["items"]:
            item_name = items[int(item)]
            item_names.append(item_name)

        row["item_names"] = item_names

        print(row)
```

Few things to highlight:

- We tell the `DictReader` that there's only one column (the first one) with the `fieldnames` arugment.
- The `restval` argument is the name given to the un-named columns (which will conveniently be a *list of values*):

  > The optional `restval` parameter specifies the value to be written if the dictionary is missing a key in fieldnames
- We use `skipinitialspace` as the values in the input have leading spaces between the commas!

We can then perform a lookup of the *exact value*, rather than a replacement!

I have chosen to build up the item list as a separate list which I add back on to the `row`.

The output from the above code is this:

```
{'person': 'Joe', 'items': ['1', '2', '1', '8'], 'item_names': ['Cigaretter', 'Snus', 'Cigaretter', 'Harebo Mix']}
{'person': 'Micky', 'items': ['19', '19', '15', '13'], 'item_names': ['Juice', 'Juice', 'Mælk', 'Ritter Sport']}
{'person': 'Berta', 'items': ['4', '3', '3', '3', '3'], 'item_names': ['Te', 'Kaffe', 'Kaffe', 'Kaffe', 'Kaffe']}
{'person': 'Frede', 'items': ['24', '22', '8', '2'], 'item_names': ['Tandpasta', 'Tandbørste', 'Harebo Mix', 'Snus']}
{'person': 'per', 'items': ['1', '9', '18', '24', '12', '22', '1', '23'], 'item_names': ['Cigaretter', 'Salt Chips', 'Kuglepen', 'Tandpasta', 'Oreo', 'Tandbørste', 'Cigaretter', 'Kondomer']}
```